# Recursion not working properly

Tags: recursion

This is a recursive solver to try to solve Euler#60.  http://projecteuler.net/problem=60
The solver runs through, but fails to find a solution for the last array member, so backtracks (like I think it's supposed to) but when I get back to the first array member, the loop runs out all the way.  Can anybody spot for me why it doesn't stop at the next prime?

I've posted just the solver function below; the other function (Concat check) works properly and returns true for a partially filled array.

```
int Solver (int primes[5])
{
    int i=1;
    int x=0;

    while (primes[x]!=0) {++x;} //work on the next one

    if ((x>5) && Concat_Check(primes)) {return 1;} //solved array

    for (i=3; i<=SIZE; i++) //try each value, if successful, return true
    {
      if (Is_Prime(i)) {primes[x]=i; cout<<"primes["<<x<<"] = "<<i<<endl;}
      if ((Concat_Check (primes)) && Solver (primes)) {return 1;}
    }
    primes[x-1] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the purpose of recursion in your code, seems a loop...
Anyway, maybe you forgot to increment `x` in loop, and the test seems incomplete.

```
for (i=3; i<=SIZE; i+=2) //try each value, if successful, return true
{
  if (Is_Prime(i)) {
    primes[x++]=i; cout<<"primes["<<x<<"] = "<<i<<endl;}
    if ((Concat_Check (primes)) && Solver (primes)) {return 1;}
  }
}
```

Comment: I am recursing because the next prime I find might work now, but not ultimately end up as a solution. I like your double increment idea, though -- no point in wasting loops on even numbers!